# I want to add a custom 404 to all my URLs following a relevant pattern using .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, google, html, indexing

Hello,

Google is currently indexing query string URLs of my website. Google has currently indexed almost 112k URLs that all of are duplicate versions of other URLs causing my website to slow down and negatively affecting my SEO.

The structure of the query strings URL is as follows: https://example.com?te=6.18.1346158.4.18.76.huffy+blue+and+white+bike

I contacted the search community earlier and they suggested me to add 404 status to the URLs with this pattern in my .htacces file.

What code should I add in my .htaccess file to block these URLs from google.

Comment: If you only want to restrict search engines, IMO a [robots.txt approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149782/ignore-urls-in-robot-txt-with-specific-parameters) would make more sense.

Comment: Are you using WordPress or PHP alone?

Comment: I am using  WordPress, Also I want to remove Google and robots.txt approach is used for crawling not indexing.